# django i18n doesn't work

Tags: django, internationalization

I have problem in django internationalization (i18n). the translation doesn't work.
my django version is : 1.5.4
This is my code:

settings.py

```
ugettext = lambda s:s
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en','English'),
    ('fa','Farsi'),
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en_us'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'templates'),
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from main import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'$^',index),
)
```

main.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
def index(request):
    alert = _('this is my page')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'alert':alert})
```

index.html

```
 {% load i18n %}
 {{alert}}
```

and then:

```
$mkdir conf/locale -p
$django-admin.py makemessages -l fa
processing language fa
$django-admin.py compilemessages
processing file django.po in /home/mori/Desktop/salam/salam/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES
```

django.po

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2013-10-15 13:12+0330\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=1; plural=0;\n"

#: main.py:4
msgid "this is my page"
msgstr "in safeye mane"
```

I have 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' in middleware class and 'django.core.context_processors.i18n' in TEMPLATE_COTEXT_PROCESSORS.

output

```
this is my page
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one thing I've forgot to consider in my `settings.py`: 
[LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#locale-paths)

Answer (score 2):

To use internationalization:

1. <strike>Define the languages your site supports.</strike>
2. <strike>Mark strings for translation.</strike>
3. <strike>Create the language files.</strike>
4. <strike>Set up the middleware in `settings.py`.</strike>
5. Set the default language of the request.

You need to [set the language for the request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), otherwise django will default to the language request coming from the browser which in your case is English.

You also need to fix your template, it should be:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans alert %}
```

In your view the `_` function only marks your string for translation; it doesn't actually translate it. Marking the string for translation makes django export it in the language files, and makes django look it up when a different language is requested by the user.

There are [a few ways that django detects the preferred language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) (it will stop at the first place it finds a language preference). These ways in the order they are checked are:

1. Language prefix in the URL, for example `/en/foo/bar/`
2. A `django_language` key in the session.
3. A `django_language` cookie.
4. `Accept-Language` header.
5. `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting.

In your case, it catching #4, because your browser is sending a list of languages it will accept, and the first one is English.

There are a few ways you can resolve this:

1. You can activate the language in your view: [`activate('fa')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.activate)
2. You can force a language in your template, with the [`language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates) template tag:

   ```
   {% load i18n %}
   {% language 'fa' %}
   {% trans alert %}
   ```
3. You can use the [url internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization) feature, and pair that with the [`set_language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) redirect view, to properly set the language and internationalize your URLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. my problems was LOCALE_PATHS that I didn't declare in settings.py.